# local variables created by a data function by a dynamic object (heap) are stored in the heap or stack?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

In C++, if I instantiate an object dynamically and it is stored in the heap, when this object calls one of its data functions which creates local variables, are these local variables stored in the heap or in the stack?

Comment: Local (non static) variables in a function/method are always on the stack.

Comment: Technically, its up to the implementation.   The standard says nothing about areas of memory called "heap" or "stack" - it simply spells out constraints on lifetime (and how initialisation works) for variables of automatic storage duration, dynamically allocated objects, statically allocated objects, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Local variables are always stored in the stack.

As soon as the function returns these data will be deallocated (destructor is called).

You can find more explanation on heap and stack differences at [What’s the difference between a stack and a heap?](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/difference-between-stack-and-heap/)

Answer (score 3):

In computer architecture there is code (as in the sequence of opcode that instructs the CPU what to do) and the data that this code acts upon. Object Orientation attempts to group code and data together but this is little more that syntactic sugar.

In C++, for non-virtual functions, the only difference between global functions and object methods is that objects methods take an implicit `this` pointer as a first parameter. Other than this, they work exactly the same with local variables stored on the stack.

Virtual functions have to use virtual tables to resolve what functions to call but other than that they are the same.

If one is using coroutines and local variable lifetime straddle a `co_await` statement, that variable may be placed on the heap so that its lifetime may extend during function suspension.